# Definition of Forward Declared Template Function Specialization

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

How to match that forward declared specialized template function for definition.
Its only a min dummy-Class and Hash and shouldn't be of concern here.
Thank you for any suggestions that solve my template issue...

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class DummyC;
namespace std {
    template<> struct std::hash<DummyC> {
        std::size_t operator()(std::shared_ptr<DummyC>&) const noexcept; }; }

#include <unordered_map>

struct DummyC{
    std::string name;
    DummyC(const std::string& n =""):name{n}{}
    bool operator ==(const DummyC& s){ return (name==s.name); }
//  DummyC():name
};

namespace std {
    template<>
        std::size_t std::hash<DummyC>::operator()(std::shared_ptr<DummyC> &d) const noexcept{
            std::size_t pH = std::hash<unsigned long>{}(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(d.get()));
            std::size_t nH = std::hash<std::string>{}(d->name);
            return nH ^ ((pH%13) & (pH>>2));
        }
}

using namespace std;
int main(){
    auto t{ make_shared<DummyC>("Dope") };
    unordered_map<shared_ptr<DummyC>,int,hash<shared_ptr<DummyC>>> tmap{{t, 50}};
    for (const auto& i: tmap) cout<<'|'<<i.first->name<<'>'<<i.second<<"|\n";
}
```

The error message I'm getting is

```
hT.cpp:23:34: error: no function template matches function template specialization 'operator()'
        std::size_t std::hash<DummyC>::operator()(std::shared_ptr<DummyC> &d) const noexcept{
```

Comment: Why are you defining your own specializations inside the `std` namespace?

Comment: To get this to compile, drop `template<>` in front of the `operator()` definition. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PqGnY1). Note however that your specialization isn't actually used for anything - you specialize `hash<DummyC>` but pass `hash<shared_ptr<DummyC>>` to the map; that's a different unrelated class.

Comment: There's a weird (and incorrect) pointer cast happening in your hash function, where you convert a `DummyC*` to `unsigned long` and then hash it.  This should be a compatible type such as `std::uintptr_t` or simply `void*`.  What's confusing it that you then go on to hash the internal string as well.  But if the pointers are equal, then the string is guaranteed equal too.  And if the strings are different, the pointer is guaranteed different.  What problem are you trying to solve here?  You should either hash the pointer or the string, but probably not both.

Comment: I suspect what you're *trying* to do is [this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7305d75bf166b233), but as you've not explained any intent beyond getting a successful compile, that's a pure guess, and not worthy of an actual answer to an unstated, non-obvious quesiton.

Comment: toooooo... many mistakes sorry but you all got it thank you!!! @IgorTandetnik: yes, i totally forgot they shared_ptr in there when trying to make the code minimal, but most importantly still dont get why i cannt make the definition a other template...

Comment: @WhozCraig thank exactly what i ment: also didnt know the hash-template-Specializion had to be const, and still dont know why you extended the includs with <functional> ...but thank you

Comment: @paddy im gonna use that hash also elsewhere on plain cout so id didnt want to leave the plain hash of the pointer in there - only little salt - but yes, void* would have been the better cast choise thank you too..

Answer (score 1):

..so just for the record and anybody looking for similar, thats the cleaned up version thanks to Igor, Paddy and WCraig

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct DummyC;
    template<> struct std::hash<std::shared_ptr<DummyC>> {
        std::size_t operator()(std::shared_ptr<DummyC> const &) const noexcept; };

#include <unordered_map>

struct DummyC{
    std::string name;
    DummyC(const std::string& n =""):name{n}{}
    bool operator ==(const DummyC& s){ return (name==s.name); }
};

    std::size_t std::hash<std::shared_ptr<DummyC>>::operator()(std::shared_ptr<DummyC> const &d) const noexcept{
        std::size_t pH = std::hash<void*>{}(reinterpret_cast<void*>(d.get()));
        std::size_t nH = std::hash<std::string>{}(d->name);
        return nH ^ ((pH%13) & (pH>>2));
    }

using namespace std;
int main(){
    auto t{ make_shared<DummyC>("Dope") };
    unordered_map<shared_ptr<DummyC>,int,hash<shared_ptr<DummyC>>> tmap{{t, 50}};
    for (const auto& i: tmap) cout<<'|'<<i.first->name<<'>'<<i.second<<"|\n";
}
```